# Google Chrome extension image

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an google chrome extension. I can set the icon for the toolbar using

```
"default_icon":   "icon.png".
```

But I can't find a method to set the extension image that appears in the extension market when you browse the extension.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set those images when you upload it to the extension directory.

Answer (score 2):

You add those images when uploading your extension to the Chrome Webstore. Here are the steps to add an icon to an existing extension.

1. Go to `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard`
2. Click `edit` [image]
3. Click `Upload new icon` [image]